# Executing a Minix kernel call

Tags: kernel, system-calls, minix

I have followed this tutorial - https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:newkernelcall to add a new kernel call, but how do I invoke it from a userspace program? I understand I should be able to use the syscall() function, but what arguments do I provide to it and what files do I need to include? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after followed https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:newkernelcall to add a Kernel Call (SYS_SAMPLE 58) in Minix 3.4.0 rc6,
I am using below code that basically coming from Example 1 of https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:driverprogramming to test this Kernel Call 58

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <minix/syslib.h>
 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sef_startup();
 
    endpoint_t ept;
    unsigned flags;

    int r = sys_sample(flags, ept);
    
    printf("Hello, World %d!\n", r);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

process:

minix code is in /home/user/minix/src/minix/

> 1. su // change to root
> 2. cp /home/user/minix/src/minix/minix/include/minix/com.h /usr/include/minix/com.h // use modified com.h while making new kernel etc.
> 3. cp /home/user/minix/src/minix/minix/include/minix/syslib.h /usr/include/minix/syslib.h

// make and use new kernel

> 4. cd /boot/minix_default/
> 5. mv kernel kernel.20240129 // back up original kernel
> 6. cd /home/user/minix/src/minix/minix/kernel
> 7. make
> 8. cp kernel /boot/minix_default/kernel

// make and use new libsys.a

> 9. cd /usr/lib
> 10. mv libsys.a libsys.a.20240129
> 11. mv libsys.so.0.0 libsys.so.0.0.20240129
> 12. cd /home/user/minix/src/minix/minix/lib/libsys
> 13. make
> 14. cp libsys.a /usr/lib/libsys.a
> 15. cp libsys.so.0.0 /usr/lib/libsys.so.0.0

// make and use new minix-service

> 16. cd /sbin
> 17. mv minix-service minix-service.20240129
> 18. cd /home/user/minix/src/minix/minix/commands/minix-service
> 19. make
> 20. make install

//make and run test driver hello1

> 21. reboot, then start Minix with Option "2"
> 22. cd /home/user/minix/src/minix/minix/drivers/examples/hello1
> 23. make clean
> 24. make
> 25. make install
> 26. minix-service up /service/hello1
> 27. minix-service down hello1

runnig result in Minix
[image]
although denied, seems called Kernel Call 58